# Decoding Image Base64 String not working

Tags: javascript, java, image, base64, byte

I needed a way to compress a selected image from client side then send it to the server and i came up with the following code in img.onload :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = url;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

if (width > height) {
if (width > max_width) {
  //height *= max_width / width;
  height = Math.round(height *= max_width / width);
  width = max_width;
}
} else {
if (height > max_height) {
  width = Math.round(width *= max_height / height);
  height = max_height;
}
}

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Then I send the base64 using ajax as follows:

```
function  sendImage(base64){
    var query = "number=0&id=012&base64="+base64;
            var url = "myImage.jsp";

            xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = postImgAjax;
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", query.length);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlHttp.send(query);
}
```

in myImage.jsp , I use the following to decode the Base64 String:

```
String imgBase64 = request.getParameter("base64");
    //BASE64Decoder d = new BASE64Decoder();
    String str = (imgBase64.split(",")[1]);
    //str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
    //System.out.println("\n "+str.replaceAll("\n", ""));
    byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes());
    //d.decodeBuffer(str.replaceAll("\\s", ""));
            //DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str.replaceAll("\\s", ""));
    Utils.save(imgBytes);
```

I spent hours trying to make this work, I've tried many possibilities ( Like using different decoder packages, removing white spaces,etc ) It keeps on throwing javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOF markers or two soi and etc.
It had few times written the bytes but the image was corrupted everytime, It was displaying a grey image instead the original.

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger if proper data is sent from web page and received on server?

Comment: Agree, first thing to check is the base64 data on the sender and receiver end, then you can pinpoint the problem. You should be able to encode a smaller jpeg first to make it easier to investigate - with a known base64 equivalent

Comment: Why are you splitting the base64 parameter?  Are you sure the base charset being used in str.getBytes() is the same being sent. Try using javascript's btoa method to see if that is better.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. Yes, the same content of the base64 is received  in the server. Actually, i've used str.getBytes() because the decoder from the apache common package doesn't take the string directly

Comment: I'm new to javascript, I'm not sure how to use the btoa method with canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. What i needed to do is to encode the base64 for url with the javascript method encodeURIComponent() . So the code that sends the base64 string looks like this:

```
function  sendImage(base64){
    var query = "number=0&id=012&base64="+encodeURIComponent(base64);
        var url = "myImage.jsp";
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = postImgAjax;
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", query.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlHttp.send(query);
}
```